# Cleaning the mailing list

Tags: list, email

I have a notepad full of 3000 mailing list but the problem is that i need to remove the duplicate emails in addition to spaces and quotations so any suggestion of a script that does this automatically instead of spending hours to fix it 
Thank you

Comment: there are numerous ways to clean that file, maybe you can provide us with what you know as language wise so someone can direct you to a better solution for you.

Comment: you get can get it done in minutes in case you don't wish to find a code for It. I had 10,000 email list.There are many free [email scrubbing](https://www.accuwebhosting.com/blog/top-10-bulk-email-list-verification-validation-services-compared/) services.

Answer (score 0):

Comming late for the party, but I adapted a script to read a file containing emails and filtering it using RFC822 regex, domain typo lists, mx lookup (thanks to eagle1 here) and ambiguous email filtering.

The script can be used like:

```
./emailCheck.sh /path/to/emailList
```

and produces two files, the filtered list and the ambiguous list. Both are already cleared from non RFC822 compliant adresses, email domains that don't have valid MX domains, and domain typos.

You may then remove duplicates with:

```
sort -u emaillist
```

Script can be found here: https://github.com/deajan/linuxscripts

Corrections and comments are welcome :)